# How get value from textbox in templatefield in gridview after buttonclick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have follow gridview and i need get value from textbox in templatefield "VyskaStavky" after i click on button. Please can someone tell me how i can do that? 
I tried something like this 
           CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")+","+Eval("VyskaStavky")%>'
but i have problem, because VyskaStavky is not property of class Kurz (my naming of datasourceID is name of class + D from data and S from source)

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="KurzDS" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Zapas" HeaderText="Zapas" SortExpression="Zapas" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AktKurz" HeaderText="AktKurz" SortExpression="AktKurz" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tip" HeaderText="Tip" SortExpression="Tip" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Handicap" HeaderText="Handicap" SortExpression="Handicap" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="VyskaStavky" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text='Podat stavku' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>'  CommandName="PodatStavku" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved My problem. I changed templete button (from command to onclick)

```
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text='Podat stavku' OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
```

and  in c# i got values

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string pk = GridView2.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"].ToString();
        TextBox ss = GridView2.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("VyskaStavky") as TextBox;
        //ss.text have my requested value
    }
```